# My jquery select dropdown is not highlighting in red color when submitting a form

Tags: jquery

```
groups: {
    Birthday: "month BirthDay Birthyear"
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (element.attr("name") == "bmonth" || element.attr("name") == "BirthDay" || element.attr("name") == "Birthyear" ) {
      error.insertAfter("#Birthyear");
    } else {
      error.insertAfter(element);
   }
  },
```

Comment: The code and the title don't seem to match each other, please include all relevant code.

Comment: can u share ur skype id @Carsten Løvbo Andersen

Comment: Nope, What I can do is to tell you that you should rewrite your question so it makes sense

Comment: all the code is nt accepting